# Image processing without deep learning or machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I am working on my graduation project and was wondering if there is a way to work on a disease detection project or an image processing project without deep learning or machine learning i have been looking for quite a long time but came with nothing.

Comment: What do you expect as an answer? For your literal question the answer is: Yes, it is possible. But I’m sure you came here wanting to learn something else. Please [edit] your question to be explicit about what you want to learn, what a useful answer would contain. And do remember that this site is about programming, not about research nor about image processing. You might instead want to consider https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computer Vision and found some promising methods that I could use to find:

1. SIFT
2. SURF
3. Template Matching
4. Image Gradients
5. Canny Edge Detection
6. Histogram of Oriented Gradients
7. Hough Line Transform
8. Hough Circle Transform
9. Gabor Filters

I experimented with all the methods using Python OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use deep learning If not, use KAZE, AKAZE. You can define some positive negative examples for each disease and check the distance.